# Ruby - NoMethodError: undefined method `reverse_merge'

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > a = {:a => 10, :b => 20}
 => {:a=>10, :b=>20} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > a.reverse_merge({:c => 30})
NoMethodError: undefined method `reverse_merge' for {:a=>10, :b=>20}:Hash
    from (irb):8
    from /home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

How to fix this `NoMethodError` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/ReverseMerge.html

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/ReverseMerge.html

Comment: Edited your answer to fix the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
reverse_merge
```

is a Rails method, not a Ruby method. Use plain old `merge`.

Comment: I think reverse merge is a method of Hash. isn't it?

Comment: @Sayuj: Rails adds this method to the `Hash` class. It's called monkeypatching. http://apidock.com/rails/Hash shows you the methods added by Rails to Hash, as opposed to those Ruby itself supplies.